# 0x124 WHEA Error Blue Screen Analysing dump files

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, crash

I'm experiencing blue screens only while attempting to stream games and not at any other time, I've tried reinstalling windows and updating all drivers, I'm not overclocking in the bios. The blue screens only ever occur when I'm actually streaming using OBS and I'm running out of ideas.. If it is a hardware issue then how do I diagnose which component is being refereed to in the dump file?

---

```
Crash Dump Analysis provided by OSR Open Systems Resources, Inc. (http://www.osr.com)
Online Crash Dump Analysis Service
See http://www.osronline.com for more information
Windows 8 Kernel Version 16299 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`0ee0d000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`0f16efd0
Debug session time: Sat Nov  4 17:25:33.768 2017 (UTC - 4:00)
System Uptime: 1 days 2:15:38.069
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffff87879bef0028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000be000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000800400, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------

TRIAGER: Could not open triage file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  TslGame.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffb600`f420a6c8 fffff801`0f71af1f : 00000000`00000124 00000000`00000000 ffff8787`9bef0028 00000000`be000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffb600`f420a6d0 fffff809`660a148a : ffff8787`9bef0028 ffff8787`96da4c10 ffff8787`96da4c10 ffff8787`96da4c10 : hal!HalBugCheckSystem+0xcf
ffffb600`f420a710 fffff801`0f08dea1 : ffff8787`9bef0028 00000000`00000000 ffff8787`96da4c10 ffff8787`96da4c10 : PSHED!PshedBugCheckSystem+0xa
ffffb600`f420a740 fffff801`0f71b460 : 00000000`00000728 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!WheaReportHwError+0x261
ffffb600`f420a7a0 fffff801`0f71b7c0 : 00000000`00000010 00000000`00000004 ffffb600`f420a948 00000000`00000004 : hal!HalpMcaReportError+0x50
ffffb600`f420a8f0 fffff801`0f71b6ae : ffff8787`96b0de60 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerCore+0xe0
ffffb600`f420a940 fffff801`0f71b8f2 : 00000000`00000008 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandler+0xda
ffffb600`f420a980 fffff801`0f71ba80 : ffff8787`96b0de60 ffffb600`f420abb0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous+0xce
ffffb600`f420a9b0 fffff801`0ef7aefb : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : hal!HalHandleMcheck+0x40
ffffb600`f420a9e0 fffff801`0ef7ac6c : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxMcheckAbort+0x7b
ffffb600`f420ab20 00007ffa`1e1c2d30 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiMcheckAbort+0x1ac
0000006a`0905f528 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x7ffa`1e1c2d30


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: GenuineIntel

IMAGE_NAME:  GenuineIntel

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

Followup: MachineOwner
```

I can provide a link to download the .DMP file if that would help, though I'm not sure about the rules on providing such a thing on here.

```
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffff87879bef0028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d354d754819956
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 11/4/2017 21:25:33 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffff87879bef00a8
Section       @ ffff87879bef0180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Micro-Architectural Error
Flags         : 0x00
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000306c3
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000004

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffff87879bef00f0
Section       @ ffff87879bef0240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000004
CPU Id        : c3 06 03 00 00 08 10 04 - bf fb fa 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffff87879bef0240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffff87879bef0138
Section       @ ffff87879bef02c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : Internal timer (Proc 4 Bank 4)
  Status      : 0xbe00000000800400
  Address     : 0x00007ff9fc3da1e5
  Misc.       : 0x00007ff9fc3da1e5
```

Comment: It’s OK to post links to things like .DMP files, but very few people will look at them. We prefer that you put all the relevant information *in* the question; but, of course, not if it’s huge.

Comment: run **!errrec ffff87879bef0028** in Windbg.exe to see more details.

Comment: @magicandre1981 updated question with the extra info

Comment: Internal timer is hard to debug. update the BIOS